# Using fullcalendar.js how do I display slot time start on every empty cell of the calendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Using fullcalendar library, I would like to display the start time for each empty cell on my calendar (empty cells are the one marked with a red cross or red dots in the below screenshot, I modified a bit the aspect of the calendar):
[image: full calendar screenshot]
So my expected output is a calendar were timeslots become buttons, when you click you start the process of booking a 30 minutes appointment which would start at the written time (the green slot is an hover effect in the following screenshot): 
[image: expected output]
I can't find any easy way to do it through after reading fullcalendar  documentation : https://fullcalendar.io/docs

Subsidiary question, I can't find the way to change the style of the empty cell in the CSS. Can't manage to select the elements through my Chrome console.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    columnHeaderHtml: function(date) {
        if (date.getUTCDay() === 0) {
        var date_day = "Lundi";
        }
        if (date.getUTCDay() === 1) {
        var date_day = "Mardi";
        }
        if (date.getUTCDay() === 2) {
        var date_day = "Mercredi";
        }
        if (date.getUTCDay() === 3) {
        var date_day = "Jeudi";
        }
        if (date.getUTCDay() === 4) {
        var date_day = "Vendredi";
        }
        if (date.getUTCDay() === 5) {
        var date_day = "Samedi";
        }
        if (date.getUTCDay() === 6) {
        var date_day = "Dimanche";
        }
        if(date.getMonth() === 0)
        {
        var date_month = "Jan";
        } 
        if(date.getMonth() === 1)
        {
        var date_month = "Fev";
        } 
        if(date.getMonth() === 2)
        {
        var date_month = "Mar";
        } 
        if(date.getMonth() === 3)
        {
        var date_month = "Avr";
        } 
        if(date.getMonth() === 4)
        {
        var date_month = "Mai";
        } 
        if(date.getMonth() === 5)
        {
        var date_month = "Juin";
        } 
        if(date.getMonth() === 6)
        {
        var date_month = "Juil";
        } 
        if(date.getMonth() === 7)
        {
        var date_month = "Août";
        } 
        if(date.getMonth() === 8)
        {
        var date_month = "Sept";
        } 
        if(date.getMonth() === 9)
        {
        var date_month = "Oct";
        } 
        if(date.getMonth() === 10)
        {
        var date_month = "Nov";
        } 
        if(date.getMonth() === 11)
        {
        var date_month = "Dec";
        } 

        var day_num = date.getDate();
        return '<b>'+date_day+'</b><br><small>'+day_num+" "+date_month+"</small>";

    },

    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'list', 'googleCalendar','timeGrid' ],
    selectable: true,

    defaultView: 'timeGridFourDay',
    views: {
        timeGridFourDay: {
            type: 'timeGrid',
            duration: { days: 4 },
            buttonText: '4 day'
        }
    },
    slotLabelFormat:{
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: '2-digit',
        omitZeroMinute: true,
        meridiem: 'short'
    },

    locale:'fr',
    header: {
        left: 'prev today',
        right: 'next'
    },
    validRange: {
        start: '2019-08-05',
        end: '2019-09-05'
    },
    allDaySlot:false,
    firstDay:1,
    minTime:"08:00:00",
    maxTime:"20:00:00",

    displayEventTime: true, // don't show the time column in list view

    // THIS KEY WON'T WORK IN PRODUCTION!!!
    // To make your own Google API key, follow the directions here:
    // http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyAL9K2UqkCVfV0n81mDW0iEpOJSwcklfsY',

    // US Holidays
    events: 'fr.fr#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',

    eventClick: function(arg) {
        arg.jsEvent.preventDefault() // don't navigate in main tab

        console.log(arg);
    },

    select: function(info) {

        console.log(info)

    },

    loading: function(bool) {

    },
    eventSources: [
    {
    googleCalendarId: 'contact@vetorino.com',
    className: "gcalEvent"

    }],

    displayEventEnd:false,
    events:[
    { // this object will be "parsed" into an Event Object

    start: '2019-08-05 12:30:00', // a property!
    end: '2019-08-05 14:00:00', // a property! ** see important note below about 'e6d' **
    overlap: true,
    backgroundColor:"#F7F7F7",
    textColor:"#979797",
    classNames:"closed",
    }],
      contentHeight: "auto",






    });

    calendar.render();

 });
```

So far as shown in my previous screenshot I just managed to have empty cells, the only cells where you find some information are cells containing events.

Comment: For styling you can just inspect the cells in chrome and see which class is common among them, them write styling for that class.

The other question is confusing, can you give more details or any reference to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: That's the funny part of this take a look at the example here : https://fullcalendar.io/#demos

Now let me know which class or element define one empty cell. I really can't find it with the console, it keeps selecting an entire row...

Comment: I added another screenshot showing the expected output. Is that clearer now?@Shakti

Comment: As you've discovered, there's no such thing as a "cell" in the HTML. The table you see is an illusion created by layering several tables on top of each other using positioning. But I don't really know why you want to clutter your calendar up with all this text anyway? In a standard time grid the slot times are already shown on the left hand side: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timegrid-standard-view-demo . I can't think why you need to copy that information over and over again for every day...the calendar will just be full of a big messy jumble of text, obscuring the events.

Comment: If you simply want to show which times are available, then use businessHours or Background Events.

Comment: @ADyson I've changed the screenshot of the expected output and added some written additional explanation just above. 

Basically my goal is to add to all free slot a button initializing the booking of an appointment which would start at the time indicated in the slot.

Comment: Another solution would be to create for every 30 minutes free slots an event. Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: "to add to all free slot a button initializing the booking" ...there's not really any need for a custom button. FullCalendar can help you detect when the user selects a slot. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback. See also https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting for related options

Comment: Yeah I know that, it's already in my code (in the "select:" part ), but I still need to change the front end so either by being able to write within these empty cells or by creating these "empty" events.

Comment: You can't write in the cells - we've already established that. But why do you need to create anything?? The slots are implicitly available because they don't already have an event on them. And if you want to make it so that certain areas are permanently unavailable then please use businessHours or background events, as I already mentioned. I'm really not sure what problem you're trying to solve here. Do you think it's not clear that these slots are available? Surely the lack of an event covering them makes it obvious?

Comment: It's a UX problem. I have to build the calendar a certain way, just check the second screenshot of my original post you'll understand what I need. A calendar like this is way more user friendly especially for the people who are going to use my product.

Everybody is not accustomed to Google Calendar and you have to ease the UX experience as much as possible. In the second screenshots you clearly understand that  on the 2nd of September you can book a meeting at 14:30, 14:50,15:10 and 15:30. In my current UX (cf. first screenshot) it's absolutely not understandable.

Comment: I think if you hadn't hidden the gridlines which are normally present in a timegrid, it would be more clear, but ok (I assume,  from your first screenshot, that you used some custom CSS to make them invisible). I can write an answer which will suggest how you might achieve it, I will try and post it shortly.

Comment: P.S. was there some particular reason you created the French day and month names manually? Did the `locale` option not work for you? I see that you have set it to `fr`, so I'd expect that to change the names automatically, if you correctly included the necessary extra file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, there is no single element in the fullCalendar HTML which represents a specific "cell" or "slot" in the timeGrid view. The grid you can see on screen is actually an illusion created by layering multiple tables on top of each other.

So to meet your requirement for a user to be able to select a 20-minute appointment in a free slot, I can see two main options. The first is what I would normally recommend, using the standard fullCalendar functionality. The second is more like what you are asking for, but I think it over-complicates things.

1) This option simply sets the calendar with a slot duration of 20 minutes, and then has code to stop the user from selecting a longer period of time (they cannot select a shorter period, due to the `slotDuration` setting. This means that they can click on any empty space once and it will know to create an event of the correct length in that location. The user is not allowed to select any slot where an event already exists. (P.S. I expect in reality you will need to collect more data before adding events, but for the demonstration it adds an event instantly.)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");

  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ["timeGrid", "interaction"],
    header: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "timeGridFourDay"
    },
    defaultView: "timeGridFourDay",
    views: {
      timeGridFourDay: {
        type: "timeGrid",
        duration: { days: 4 },
        buttonText: "4 day"
      }
    },
    slotLabelFormat: {
      hour: "numeric",
      minute: "2-digit",
      omitZeroMinute: true,
      meridiem: "short"
    },
    allDaySlot: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    minTime: "08:00:00",
    maxTime: "20:00:00",
    contentHeight: "auto",
    slotDuration: "00:20:00",
    selectable: true,
    select: function(info) {
      //console.log(info);
      calendar.addEvent({ "title": "Test", start: info.start, end: info.end })
      calendar.unselect();
    },
    selectOverlap: false,
    selectAllow: function(selectInfo) {
      var stM = moment(selectInfo.start);
      var enM = moment(selectInfo.end);
      var diff = enM.diff(stM, "minutes");
      console.log(diff);
      if (diff > 20)
      {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    },
    events: [
      { "title": "Existing event", "start": "2019-08-08 10:00", "end": "2019-08-08 10:20"},
      { "title": "Existing event", "start": "2019-08-08 13:20", "end": "2019-08-08 13:40"},
]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/aeqJQg

---

2) This option is closer to your desired UI (from your 2nd screenshot) but is a bit more complicated to achieve. I also, personally, think it leaves your calendar looking cluttered, and making it harder to see where the free and busy slots are, but ultimately it's up to you how you want to implement it. This works by adding a second event source, containing a list of all currently free slots. These are then used to display the start time of each free slot in the centre of it. They are coloured differently from the existing events (indicating a busy slot), so that it's a bit easier to tell the difference.

Of course, this requires you to use your server-side code to calculate all the currently free slots in your database and use that information to populate the second event source. (In the demo the free slot data is static, but of course that will not work in a real application.)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");

  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ["timeGrid", "interaction"],
    header: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "timeGridFourDay"
    },
    defaultView: "timeGridFourDay",
    views: {
      timeGridFourDay: {
        type: "timeGrid",
        duration: { days: 4 },
        buttonText: "4 day"
      }
    },
    slotLabelFormat: {
      hour: "numeric",
      minute: "2-digit",
      omitZeroMinute: true,
      meridiem: "short"
    },
    allDaySlot: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    minTime: "08:00:00",
    maxTime: "20:00:00",
    contentHeight: "auto",
    slotDuration: "00:20:00",
    displayEventTime: false,
    eventClick: function(info) {
        if (info.event.extendedProps.type == "free") {
          calendar.addEvent({
            title: "Test",
            start: info.event.start,
            end: info.event.end
          });
          info.event.remove(); //delete the "free slot" event
        }
    },
    eventSources: [
      {
        id: "busy",
        events: [
          {
            title: "Existing event",
            start: "2019-08-08 10:00",
            end: "2019-08-08 10:20"
          },
          {
            title: "Existing event",
            start: "2019-08-08 13:20",
            end: "2019-08-08 13:40"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "free",
        backgroundColor: "green",
        events: [
          {
            title: "08:00",
            start: "2019-08-08 08:00",
            end: "2019-08-08 08:20",
            type: "free"
          },
          {
            title: "08:20",
            start: "2019-08-08 08:20",
            end: "2019-08-08 08:40",
            type: "free"
          },
          {
            title: "08:40",
            start: "2019-08-08 08:40",
            end: "2019-08-08 09:00",
            type: "free"
          },
          {
            title: "09:00",
            start: "2019-08-08 09:00",
            end: "2019-08-08 09:20",
            type: "free"
          },
          {
            title: "09:20",
            start: "2019-08-08 09:20",
            end: "2019-08-08 09:40",
            type: "free"
          },
          {
            title: "09:40",
            start: "2019-08-08 09:40",
            end: "2019-08-08 10:00",
            type: "free"
          },
          {
            title: "10:20",
            start: "2019-08-08 10:20",
            end: "2019-08-08 10:40",
            type: "free"
          },
          {
            title: "10:40",
            start: "2019-08-08 10:40",
            end: "2019-08-08 11:00",
            type: "free"
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

For this demo I only created handful of the "free" slots (because it was tedious to create them), but hopefully you can get the idea of how it would start to look with dozens of them all over the calendar. Of course again you can amend the CSS to your requirements.

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/JgpNEX

(You can of course amend the CSS of this further to make it appear more like your desired look and feel.)

Addendum: Here's the OP's final version, for anyone who is interested in the end product - based on taking the above suggestions into consideration: https://codepen.io/hugo-trial/pen/rXdajv

Comment: Thanks a lot for your wonderful contribution. I loved the 20 minutes slot duration thing.
I'm going for an Hybrid solution between your options and something I came up with quite late last night. Instead of creating events, I'm just adding some empty cell on calendar instantiation and refreshing thanks to eventRender. I'm almost there, I just have some issues with the rendering not being the same at every webpage refresh.

When I'm done I'll post my answer and give you credit for your huge input. Thanks again.

Comment: So here is my solution : https://codepen.io/hugo-trial/pen/rXdajv

The only issue I have is that there is an issue on the first calendar display of the event loaded from my google calendar. I don't know why the event is not on the right spot. If I click on the calendar though, the google calendar events are moved to the right spot. Any idea what is doing this and how I could fix it?

Comment: Resizing the window also makes the event move to the right spot. Very weird.

Comment: I think your temp cells are messing with the height of the rows in the grid. And the events are positioned absolutely on top of what fullCalendar thinks is the correct position in the grid. If you comment out the eventRender code then it shows up in the correct place first time. Resizing the window will potentially cause the calendar to re-draw, so it then has an opportunity to correct itself. I don't know the source code of fullCalendar in loads of detail, but I'm guessing that's what's probably happening

Comment: In fact from playing with it a little bit, it seems to be the fixed height of 41px on the buttons which causes the problem. Removing that rule from CSS fixes it. You can get away with setting a height of 30px or lower without breaking it, by the looks of it (at least on my screen size, in CodePen, with the calendar dimensions as they are - it might differ in another layout. Using fixed heights/widths in general probably isn't the way to go, as fullCalendar calculates its dimensions more fluidly. Maybe try and use % instead if you can.)

Comment: P.S. fullCalendar's drawing algorithms are very accurate in my experience. Whenever someone asks a question on this site along the lines of "my fullCalendar layout is broken", it's _always_ their own custom CSS which has caused the issue.

Comment: Thanks!!!
I just selected this post as the right answer. I think it would be great if you add my CodePen link into the answer just to complete your answer, I've of course updated it based on your CSS comment.

Completely agree with you, it's a hell of a beautiful piece of javascript ;)

Now next step for me is to find a way not to create the Blue buttons:
- on cells where there is already an event (even partially covering the time slot)
- on cells where the office is closed.
I'm planing to spend a lot of time on jQuery now ahahah. Thanks again for being such a nice person

Comment: Thanks for being so patient with me while I tried to pick apart your motives and check you really wanted and needed what you were asking for! I've added your CodePen link into the answer. The formula to not create the blue buttons will be fun...I'm half wondering whether it might be best done server side (assuming you have a database of events on the server) so you can query your stored list of existing events. Then you can give your JavaScript a list of dates/times on which not to create a button, and have it check the list before rendering them. That would be my initial way of approaching it

Comment: No need to thanks me for that my initial post was messy it needed some additional inputs. Well I thought about that, but then there are the events coming from google calendar which I don't have a direct access to. So I'm trying to find a way to query the calendar once all events are rendered to know for which timeslot there are ongoing events and then remove for these the generated blue buttons. But it seems quite hard to do, fullcalendar would need a getEvent(date/time) function which I don't think it has right now :( If you have an alternative idea I'm all ears ahah!

Comment: fullCalendar does have https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents which will return all the events in the calendar, and you could then loop through them and filter by the date. Not ideal, but also the other issue you'll run up against is that you'd have to wait until all the google events have rendered before you start drawing the buttons - and fullCalendar doesn't provide a callback to tell you when that's happened.

Comment: P.S. I forgot to mention that drawing your buttons inside eventRender isn't all that efficient - eventRender will run once for each event it downloads from google, so you're probably repeating the creation of your buttons several times over. Equally, if you have no events in a particular month, then you might find it doesn't draw them at all, because eventRender would never run. It probably makes more sense to run it in the datesRender callback instead: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesRender

Comment: To get round the waiting for events to download issue, one thing you could consider doing is fetching the google data on the server-side instead, and then passing on the results to fullCalendar (so fullCalendar thinks the event feed is coming from your server instead), which would give you the opportunity to examine them, and calculate your free slots, before they are downloaded. It might end up costing you a bit of speed, but it might be simpler.

Comment: Thanks for these two new valuable inputs, I'll check it out. I came to a weird bug when executing the code on my local server. The first time I'm displaying the calendar everything works well, but if I refresh the page, sometimes the google calendar events would not appear, or the blue buttons become very small : https://postimg.cc/fk0y6QZM

Comment: That is odd. But I'm afraid I can't fix a bug just by looking at a picture :-)

Comment: Completely agree but since it is linked to Caching I can't reproduce it on codepen.io :/ This is very weird. I think I'll have to find out by myself.